# How do I force git to NOT LET ME COMMIT until I remove debugging code?

Tags: git

While debugging I sometimes screw up the codebase, and I don't want it to be possible for me to leave in debugging code.

Example:

```
// NOCOMMIT: It's annoying that this thing keeps getting deleted while testing
// db_query('DELETE FROM pdf WHERE password=?', [$password]);
```

I don't want git to allow me to commit until I remove the `NOCOMMIT:` comment (and remember to uncomment the SQL call!)

Comment: ...with a pre-commit hook? However, that won't stop you forgetting to put in the comments. Have you considered automated testing?

Comment: Use gerrit instead of git. Make sure that reviewers know not to let debugging code through. People are so much more reliable than computers.

Comment: [Docs for hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know hooks were a thing! (thanks for the other non-hook suggestions too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks). You can write a hook in pretty much any scripting language (e.g. Bash or Ruby).

You would need to make a `pre-commit` hook. You put this in your `path/to/repo/.git/hooks/` directory. In fact, you can even read the samples already there.

Your hook would need to look at the list of modified files, grep through for a note (e.g. `NOCOMMIT` or `TODO`), and then continue or break based on the findings.

You can run this command to get a list of modified files separated by new lines.

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD
```

Comment: One side note: if you `git add` a file with some debug code, then *remove* the debug stuff but don't `git add` again, the version set up for commit has the debug stuff in it, but looking at the modified file in the work directory, you won't see the debug code.  This means your "look through" code should look at the *staged* files, if possible (well, it's always *possible* but it might be too annoying to bother with).